# Save custom value to main content of post

Tags: save-post

I create a meta custom input to make a page builder. So i can drop & drag element to build content for post.

And when i save post, i want it will save directly to post content.

So i think i will change the $_POST and hook it to save_post action.

`$_POST['content'] = $_POST['page-builder-content'];`

I have try but it does not work. Any advises ?
Code:

```
function stPageBuilder() {
    $screens = array('post', 'page');

    foreach ($screens as $screen) 
    {
        add_meta_box(
            'st-post-class',            // Unique ID
            esc_html__( 'Page Builder', page-builder' ),        // Title
            'stPageBuilderCallBack',        // Callback function
            $screen,                    // Admin page (or post type)
            'advanced',                 // Context
            'default'                   // Priority
        );
    }
}

function stPageBuilderCallBack($post, $box) {
    wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'st-page-builder-nonce' );
    // here is html layout for drag & drop feature
}

function stPageBuilderSave($postID) 
{
    if ('page' == $POST['post_type']) {
        if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $postID)) return;
    } else {
        if (!current_user_can('edit_post', $postID)) return;
    }

    if (!isset($_POST['st-page-builder-nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['st-page-builder-nonce'], basename(__FILE__))) return;

    $_POST['content'] = $_POST['st-page-builder-content'];

}

function staddPageBuilder() {
    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'stPageBuilder' );    
    add_action( 'save_post', 'stPageBuilderSave' );
}

staddPageBuilder();
```

Comment: Why do you want to save meta box content into post content?

Comment: I create a custom metabox content instead for post's editor. If i want to it present in front page, so i need to save it into post content.

Comment: ok. I got it but the above code that you have added in question does not display any textbox or textarea to enter content in it. Did you miss to copy it here or you have not created it?

Comment: in function stPageBuilderCallBack i will include a form to do it. I sure have a custom value, the only thing we need to save this value to post content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer appears to be clear if you look at the source code. The action you're hooking to occurs inside `wp_insert_post`, and is called just before it returns the `$post_ID` variable. This means that all the manipulation and data insertion has already taken place, so modifying the `$_POST` array will do nothing. You must look for things to do prior to database modification for your changes to have any effect. Luckily, WordPress has many options to choose from.

In short, here's what I would do:

```
//  Hook to a different action / filter
function staddPageBuilder() {
    // ...
    add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'stPageBuilderSave', 10, 2);
}

// Notice the new filter passes different arguments, so we need to adapt the function
function stPageBuilderSave($data, $postarr) 
{
    // Since we don't have the $postID variable, let's try to grab it from the array passed by the insert function
    // Note that passing the object ID to the current_user_can function is very unusual and you can do without it
    $postID = isset($postarr['ID']) ? $postarr['ID'] : 0;

    if ('page' == $POST['post_type']) {
        if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $postID)) return;
    } else {
        if (!current_user_can('edit_post', $postID)) return;
    }

    if (!isset($_POST['st-page-builder-nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['st-page-builder-nonce'], basename(__FILE__))) return;

    // This bit changes, because the action is different and so are the function's arguments
    $data['post_content'] = $_POST['st-page-builder-content'];
    return $data;
}
```

Let us know how it goes!

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using [wp_insert_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) function from WordPress to insert post into post content

Example:

```
// Create post object
$my_post = array(
  'post_title'    => 'My post',
  'post_content'  => 'This is my post.',
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_author'   => 1,
  'post_category' => array(8,39)
);

// Insert the post into the database
wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

Comment: He's already hooking to an action **inside** wp_insert_post. Calling this function within his existing logic can cause an infinite loop. You should clarify what you intend for him to do.

Comment: This will create another post, not update an existing one. You *could* use `wp_update_post()` on the `save_post` hook, but beware the infinite loop: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post#Avoiding_infinite_loops

Comment: Plus what @StephenHarris said; always with the sharper eye :)